# golang mongodb migrate database library mongo to mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I want to change library for database from `github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo` to  `github.com/globalsign/mgo`, my problem is I dont know how convert this code for new library :

```
import "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/options"
res, err := s.totals().UpdateOne(ctx,
        bson.M{"contract_id": cID, "date": date},
        bson.M{"$inc": bson.M{"value": value}},
        options.Update().SetUpsert(true),
    )
```

My current code :

```
collection := s.totals()
err := collection.Update(
    bson.M{"contract_id": contractID, "date": date},
    bson.M{"$inc": bson.M{"value": value}},
    //options.Update().SetUpsert(true),
)
```

How i can convert this `options.Update().SetUpsert(true)` for use in new library ?

Comment: Mgo is deprecated. The MongoDB "official" Go driver was created due to that project being abandoned.

Comment: I would carefully consider using a fork, of a fork, of a fork, of an unmaintained project.

Comment: @JimB The official MongoDB Go driver is still in a pre-release state, although it's getting close to a stable 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the [`Collection.Upsert()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Collection.Upsert) method instead of [`Collection.Update()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Collection.Update):

```
info, err := collection.Upsert(
    bson.M{"contract_id": contractID, "date": date},
    bson.M{"$inc": bson.M{"value": value}},
)
```

Quoting from the doc of `Collection.Upsert()`:

> Upsert finds a single document matching the provided selector document and modifies it according to the update document. **If no document matching the selector is found, the update document is applied to the selector document and the result is inserted in the collection.**